# Download a file from writable stream from a fastify nodejs web server running in a container to a user's machine

Tags: node.js, fastify, node-streams

I am trying to figure out how one can download the actual file generated from a writable stream to the user's machine, from a nodejs webserver leveraging on the fastify's framework.

#### What I've tried so far

I did create the readable stream by reading a file then gzipped it using zlib and piped the result to a writeable stream.
With that approach, the file gets downloaded to the docker container's runtime environment.

However, I'd like to be able to get the streamed file directly into my local file system i.e for instance by making a GET request to the web server using curl.

Here's a glimpse of the code:

```js
'use strict'
const path = require('node:path');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');
const zlib = require('zlib');

module.exports = async function(fastify, opts) {
  fastify.get('/', async function(request, reply) {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path.dirname(__dirname) + '/package.json');
    const writeStreamPath = path.resolve('/tmp','zipped.json.gz');
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(writeStreamPath);

    try {
      await pipeline(
        readStream,
        zlib.createGzip(),
        writeStream,
      );

      return reply.send('Pipeline successful');
    } catch (err) {
      fastify.log.error('pipeline failed', err.message);
      throw err;
    }
  });
}
```

I'm also aware that fastify does not provide a `reply.download()` utility like express js.
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to resolve this using [@fastify/static](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static).
First I did register the plugin and set the root attribute to that of the os's temporary directory.

```
...
const tempPath = await fs.mkdtemp(os.tmpdir());
await fastify.register(require('@fastify/static', {
 root: tempPath,
});
```

Then as for the write stream path, I joined the temp path with that of the filename.
After, I was able to retrieve the file by using curl i.e

```
curl https://endpointname/param?query='value' -OJ
```

and got the file in my local; where I actually invoked the GET request.